# Laravel - Cannot get updated config value when using helper function

Tags: php, laravel, config, multisite

I'm trying to get the config value when assigning the value to config via a helper function. For better understanding, let me give you an example:

Here is my `config/app.php` file:

```
// config/app.php

return [
  'name' => load_multisite_env('APP_NAME')
];
```

and the helper function used in `config/app.php` is:

```
// Helper Function

function load_multisite_env($key) {
  return env(
    config('active.site') . $key, 
    env($key, null)
  );
}
```

And the value of `config('active.site')` will be set from `AppServiceProvider` as:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider

public function boot() {
  config(['active.site' => request()->get('active_site') ]);
}
```

While if I try the helper function from the controller then it returns the correct value, but when I try to access the value through the config, it doesn't work.

As it looks like that the config value gets loaded before I set the `active.set` from the service provider.

**Question** is: How I can get the updated values of env in the config file after the app has been loaded?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.